# Thermostat and thermostat system for small business with several units and tenants

Tags: hvac

Am the facilities guy in a small church and pre-school.  There are 8 heat pump units through out the church/schoool.  Each has a stand-alone thermostat and they are all different.

I would like to get to a setup where:

1. Thermostats are set to a schedule managed centrally, preferably cloud solution.
2. Users can change temp temporarily when in meeting to override but its not permanent.  Has local sensor to see if anyone is present.
3. That different groups can set the schedule and set points for their part of the system - i.e. the pre-school can set a schedule for when they are in session but it does not override at other times.

I have looked at most of them and:

- Most are oriented at home market
- Most don't handle different groups
- Most assume that all touching of the thermostat is by members of the household and OK.

Any suggestions?